# React - How can I redirect to another page after some conditions are met on the OnClick of a Button?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So in this component, I have a button called Submit which when clicked will do the following operations: it will export the drawing that the user has made as a jpeg url, pass it to another api that returns an image caption, then compares this image caption to a string prompt that was returned prior.  I would like to redirect the user to another webpage based on whether the comparison between the image caption and the prompt was the same or not.  How would I go about this?

```js
   <button onClick={() => { 
           
            let W = this.handleWord()
            let valid = this.state.valid

            this.canvas.current.exportImage("jpeg") 
            
              .then(imagedata => { 
                fetch('https://hf.space/embed/Salesforce/BLIP/+/api/predict/', { method: "POST", body: JSON.stringify({"data":[imagedata,"Image Captioning","None","Beam Sampling"]}), headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" } })
                .then(function(response) { 
                  return response.json(); })
                .then(function(json_response)
                {blip = json_response.data 
                
                valid = blip.includes(W) //blip which is a string returned by the api above is checked to see if W is in the string
                console.log(valid)
                  //based on this valid boolean, i want to have page be redirected to either Success or Share, two seperate pages ive made

                })
              })
              .catch(e => {
                console.log(e);
              });
          }}

          className='buttonprops'>

            <img src={submitbutton} width = {120} height = {35} alt = 'Submit!' />
            
            </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const YourComponent = () => {
  // if you're using react-router...
  const navigate = useNavigate(); // import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'

  const handleClick = () => {
   // your button click logic...
   navigate(valid ? "/success" : "/share")

   // or if you're not using react-router...
   window.location.pathname = valid ? "/success" : "/share"
  }

  return <button onClick={handleClick}>click me</button>
}
```